# Regarding PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is the problem in below plsql? I am running this code in sql developer.

```
BEGIN
 FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM dba_tables WHERE owner = 'ABPPMGR_TE2' AND table_name IN
            (select object_name from dba_objects where object_type = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW' and status = 'VALID')
          )
  LOOP
     dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( x.owner, x.table_name); 
  END LOOP;
END;
```

It gives the error:

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " "
>   when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for
>   goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with   
>   << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge The symbol "
>   " was ignored.

Comment: "What is the problem?" We don't know... What is the problem? Does it give an error? Does it do something unexpected? ...

Comment: It is giving below error in sql developer:

Comment: ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
The symbol " " was ignored.

Comment: Are you sure you are running it the "right" way? This works well for me.

Comment: Maybe some invisible characters. Did you copy and paste that code from e.g. Word or some other non-plain text editor?

Comment: is there a declaration part above this code statement? If no, there seems no problem exists with this.

Comment: ohh ... It ran fine..there was some special character.... thanks

Comment: In SQL Developer there would have been a little red squiggle between the `FOR` and `x`, indicating something odd there; you actually have [a non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) at the start of that line, and there are five others in that block. Replacing those with normal spaces, or just copying and pasting the code from this question (as displayed above, not the raw markdown text in edit mode), would have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tired it as is and it worked fine for me as well.  I will try to include the screenshot.

Best.[image: Successful run screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you have a "strange" characters on your code,
its very common when you copy something from forums or websites.

When I ran your code and I find some character that resembles a space (' ') but arent spaces, and received the same erro that you got, 
you can run ASCII function to check it.

```
SELECT ASCII(' ') FROM dual; -- strange character that returns ascii code 160
SELECT ASCII(' ') FROM dual; -- normal space returns 32
```

Just remove all the strange characters from your code and it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to see if there are any Non-Ascii characters in your code using below query

```
select asciistr('BEGIN
 FOR x  IN
 (SELECT *
 FROM dba_tables
 WHERE owner     = ''ABPPMGR_TE2''
 AND table_name IN
   (SELECT object_name
    FROM dba_objects
   WHERE object_type = ''MATERIALIZED VIEW''
   AND status        = ''VALID''
   )
 )
  LOOP
   dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( x.owner, x.table_name);
 END LOOP;
END') from dual;
```

Did not find any Non-Ascii characters. The code seems correct to me as it executed without any issues on my system.